# How to get average velocity of all the cars using opticalFlow in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing, opticalflow, matlab-cvst

I stumbled with this link http://www.mathworks.com/products/computer-vision/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/vision/videotrafficof.html

This has been very useful to me but i just can't figure out how to get the average velocity or speed of all the objects detected. Please help me.

Comment: Do you need speed of apparent motion in pixels/frame, or the actual speed of the cars in world units?

Comment: pixels /frame is okay.

Answer (score 1):

Given a video and computing optical flow cannot get you the speed of an object, however it can help you in estimating the relative speed of objects at the same depth. For computing the speed the camera needs to be calibrated and then you can compute the speed of vehicles using optical flow.